# What does prefixing an object with '+' operator do?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I came across this line of code in Underscore.js's _.each implementation and I am curious what is going on here.  What does the '+' in front of the obj do?

`if (obj.length === +obj.length) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` tests that `obj.length` is numeric and not `NaN`. The right-hand side is always a number (or `NaN` if `obj.length` cannot be interpreted as a number). It will only be `===` to the left-hand side if `obj.length` is also a number.

Note that using `isNaN` won't work if `obj.length` is a numeric-looking string; that is, `isNan("3")` returns `false`. Note also that `NaN === NaN` is `false`—`NaN` is never `===` to anything.

Comment: So what is the point of comparing the same object's .length property, once as a 'forced number' and once not? what does this accomplish?

Comment: @alnafie - I'd have to look at the code to know, but my initial guess would be that it's gate around code that either requires that `obj.length` be a number or else some expensive code to calculate `obj.length` that should be skipped if it's already properly set.